# Google API for walking detection

Tags: android, google-api, sensors

Can DetectedActivity be used to detect when a user is moving indoors? Does it require GPS signal or just sensor fusion? If not, is there any Android or Google API that can detect movements like walking?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity

Answer (score 0):

Using Android APIs, you can register a listener for step counter or step detector sensors. It doesn't require an access to the GPS.

Comment: Unfortunately the portion of the devices with this hardware seems really small.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the step-count using Google Fit Api, have a look here - https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types